# Socialite registration (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-socialite

I'm making a Laravel 5.4 project where I want users to select a school (which they will be assigned to) before they register and the user is created.
My problem is that a google login is the main login method of the application and the user creation is handled in the LoginController. I'm using the Socialite package for the google login.

How do I pass the user and the data from the google callback to the register page?

This is my LoginController:

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    try 
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        return redirect('auth/google');
    }

    $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user);

    Auth::login($authUser, true);

    return redirect('/home');
}

public function findOrCreateUser($googleUser)
{
    $authUser = User::where('google_id', $googleUser->id)->first();

    if ($authUser) {
        return $authUser;
    }

    return User::create([
        'name' => $googleUser->name,
        'email' => $googleUser->email,
        'google_id' => $googleUser->id,
        'avatar' => $googleUser->avatar
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [flashed session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data).
Try this:

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    try 
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        return redirect('auth/google');
    }

    $authUser = User::where('google_id', $user->id)->first();

    if($authUser) //if user is found
    {
        Auth::login($authUser, true);
        return redirect('/home');
    }
    else //if user is not found, redirect to register page
    {
        return redirect('/register')->with('user', $user);
    }
}
```

and in your register view

```
<input type='text' name='email' value='{{session("user")->email}}'>
```